# Multiple row selection lost on right click in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

When I right click the row header to enable context menu in a `DataGrid`, multiple selection is lost. I tried the below code to retain it but it didn't work.

Whenever the selection changes, I update the `selectedRowsindex` list.
When I right click the row header, selection automatically changes to the row the mouse is pointing to. So I unsubscribe the `SelectionChanged` event. I have added an event to the `RowHeader`.

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
           <EventSetter Event="ContextMenuOpening" Handler="RowHeader_ContextMenuOpening"/>
           <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}"/>
      </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

When the context menu is opened from the row header, I update the selected rows of the Grid.

```
List<int> selectedRowsIndex = new List<int>();

private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    selectedRowsIndex.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
       selectedRowsIndex.Add(dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(dataGrid.SelectedItems[i]));
    }
}

private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
     while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRowHeader))
     {
      dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
     }
     if (dep is DataGridRowHeader)
     {
        dataGrid.SelectionChanged -= DataGrid_SelectionChanged;
     }
}

private void RowHeader_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGrid.SelectionChanged -= DataGrid_SelectionChanged;
    dataGrid.SelectedItems.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowsIndex.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGrid.SelectedItems.Add(dataGrid.Items[selectedRowsIndex[i]]);
    }
    //Edit : Added the following code. Still isn't working
    DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
     while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRowHeader))
     {
      dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
     }
     if (dep is DataGridRowHeader)
     {
        DataGridRowHeader rowHeader = dep as DataGridRowHeader;
        rowHeader.ContextMenu = dataGrid.FindResource("RowMenu") as ContextMenu;
     }
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

Edit : I tried adding the context menu programatically in the `RowHeader_ContextMenuOpening` method. It still is not working.